What's the difference between the Urban House genre and Moombathon genre?
Supposedly Moombahton is a fusion between Reggaeton music and House music. I could find a reference here Moombathon .
In the spanish speaking world, between music producers, there is also many mentions to a genre called Urban House, which is also a fusion between Reggaeton and House music. If my observations are correct, it has the melodic part of Reggaeton and the Rithmic part of House music, mainly Deep House. I couldnt find any reference explaining this genre, but here there is a sample of it URBAN HOUSE 2022. Things get even more complicated when Reggaeton itself is a fusion of Reggae, Hip Hop, DanceHall, and according to rapper Daddy Yankee, considered the "King of Reggaeeton", a fusion of all those genres with House music itself, and other caribbean genres.
So basically my question is, what's the difference between the Urban House genre and Moombathon genre?

I'm not an expert in either genre, but one difference that jumps out from listening to the links you provided is that Moombathon has the distinctive reggaeton stutter beat, while the Urban House beat has much more of the 4-on-the-floor house feel.
Tempo is mentioned as a key factor in the Wikipedia article--the Moombathon music is notably slower than the Urban House music. Even in the Urban House songs that do have a stutter beat, the faster pace means that it's not as prominent.
